# Cryptography: Oblivious Transfer with at most one transfer?

Tags: quantum-cryptography, oblivious-transfer

I am trying find a transfer method for this problem. Suppose Alice and Bob both has access to a function $\text{F}$ with two parameters. $\text{F}(x,y)$ randomly returns $p$ to alice and $q$ to Bob  such that $x\times y=p \oplus q$. Now as per rules of Oblivious Transfer, Alice has $s_0$ and $s_1$ and Bob has $c$. Bob wants to learn $Sc$. The catch is alice can transfer at most one bit in total to bob, that means they can communicate just once. How can Bob learn $Sc$ using this function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Protocol for Randomized Oblivious Transfer?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1119/protocol-for-randomized-oblivious-transfer)

Comment: Nope; the solution listed as a duplicate doesn't meet the criteria; Alice sends back two bits, not just one...

Comment: @poncho If the solution listed as a duplicate doesn't meet the criteria, why leave the close vote? Is it a duplicate nevertheless? Maybe I'm confused because it's late (2AM) and I could imagine there's an obvious reason, but somehow I'm not getting it... probably due to the "Nope" which contradicts the "dupe" vote.

Comment: I am finding this question hard to follow.  What do you mean by a "transfer method"?  What is $Sc$?  Do you mean $s_c$?  What counts as bits transferred to Bob?  Can they invoke $F$ as many times as they want?  Who provides the inputs to $F$ (does $x$ come from Alice and $y$ from Bob)?  Are we guaranteed that $p,q$ are chosen randomly subject to the condition that $p \oplus q = x \times y$?  Please edit the question to make the problem statement clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious approach is to help Bob learn $s_0 \oplus (s_0 \oplus s_1) \times c$, presumably using $F$ to help him learn this information.  So, here is the natural protocol:

- Alice and Bob invoke $F$.  Alice provides the input $s_0 \oplus s_1$, Bob provides the input $c$.  Alice learns $p$ and Bob learns $q$, where we are guaranteed that $p \oplus q = (s_0 \oplus s_1) \times c$.
- Alice sends $p \oplus s_0$ to Bob.

Notice that, with this information Bob can compute $s_c$.  I leave it as an exercise to you how to do that.

Also, notice that Bob learns only one of $s_0,s_1$.  I leave it to you as an exercise to prove that.

Finally, notice that if $F$ does not disclose anything about its inputs to either part, then Alice does not learn anything about Bob's bit $c$.